# Android Okhttp Request Not Responding

Tags: android, json, network-programming, okhttp

I'm trying to Post JSON object in my application's login page. I searched for many examples and tried for them. But only my android 4.3 devices is running well and the other upper api level devices is not even response coming back. My code like below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.LoginBtn:
            loading.show();

            try {
                login();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;



    }
}

public void login(){
    okhttp3.OkHttpClient client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    final JSONObject JObje = new JSONObject();
    try {

        JObje.put("Username", String.valueOf(Username.getText()));
        JObje.put("Password", String.valueOf(Password.getText()));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    okhttp3.Request request = null;
    okhttp3.RequestBody body = null;

    body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .addEncoded("JSONVALUE", String.valueOf(JObje))
            .build();

    request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .url(context.getString(R.string.rutKontrolServis))
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .post(body)
            .build();


    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.d("TAG","responded");
            }
        });
}
```

the R.string.rutKontrolServis url is like this: https://ourwebsite.com/folder/package_name.mywebservice

In my gradle file I added dependency this:
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'

Is there any different request syntax or any constraint about tls or ssl certificates with newer api level devices? Can someone show a point

Comment: Try printing the `IOException` in `onFailure()`. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to increase the connection timeout and read timeout? I think 10 seconds is too short:

```
okhttp3.OkHttpClient client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
```

Increase to 30 seconds and try again.

Comment: You can print log onFailure, we might get some error message.

Comment: There is no response positive and negative, so it is not entering to onFailure method

Comment: So strange. how about another settings(add permissions to Manifest file, check network connection...). If everything is ok, you can try with some public APIs like: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Comment: These settings is normal for my android 4.3 devices. But other devices is not responding or giving any error. I suspect with security part, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes OkHTTP just suddenly stops responding - no onFailure results, no onResponse results, even after increasing timeout. Nothing.
Switching your wifi / network provider to another provider worked for me.